# One-to-Many reference count

Tags: android, realm

Have another question here.

Consider the following database model (with mutual relationships):

- a software (some `RealmObject` with some `PrimaryKey` id);
- clients who use it (**each client is of its own type that extends** `RealmObject`);

How do I query Realm for "how many clients do use the software that has `id=<desired_id>`"? The problem is that *each client is of different type*. There may be `class Company extends RealmObject` and `class Person extends RealmObject` and `class IndieDeveloper extends RealmObject` and many more.

Since inheritance isn't implemented yet I cannot model the database such way that every client has the base class of, say, `Client` and query for it.

I didn't find any solution yet. I don't think querying for each known type is an option for my particular case. There may be many different client types (as shown in example).

Thanks.

Comment: If your `Software` contains `Client` then you need backlink which is not supported yet, See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607 . If `Client` contains  `Software` , you can use link query to achieve that, see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries

Comment: @beeender Either you misread me again or I misunderstood you. As I said in the post I _can not_ simply create the `Client` class as Realm does not support inheritance. Hence I have to create different RealmObjects like `Company` or `Person` - whoever may refer to `Software` as "I use this software so I hold a reference to it".

Again, this is just an example. My structure that I'm required to create is much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `[RealmList][1]` for that:

Have a look at the official documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many

Comment: How can I achieve it with `RealmList`? I need to get backward references - like what Object has referenced my particular child. I could store back references to parents in the child but again - first, I don't always know the type of parent. Second, it kinda kills the purpose.